# How do you input Virgin Money Giving Donations into CiviCRM?

Tags: donations, facebook

Just a quick question, is there any better way to get donations from outside services like Virgin Money Giving or Facebook that just manual input?

At the moment, I'm just assuming that we add the contact/donation manually into the system with the source being "Facebook Page" or "Virgin Money Giving" or whatever it may be.

Any suggestions on how any other NFPs are doing this with Civi at the moment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you can export the donations out of those systems in a CSV then you could import the contributions to Civi.

There is fairly old extension for [importing Just Giving donations](https://civicrm.org/extensions/just-giving-imports).  Don't know whether it still works but would be a base for developing an automated import.  Once it is working you could add a Scheduled Job to do the import regularly.  Obviously you need to be careful to avoid importing the same donation in multiple batches.

Comment: Thanks Aidan, will check out that link you posted.